# JPA table is not created for @Entity annotation if it in another package

Tags: java, jpa, entity, apache-karaf

I am using `JPA` with `karaf` implementation, In that, I am using  `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` strategy. So I am having parent class in package - `org.abc.model`, and child is in package `org.abc.model.child`. Now the problem is the table is not created for the child class.

Note: If am moving child class from `org.abc.model.child` to `org.abc.model` the table got created.

Comment: By default, Karaf offers support for EclipseLink and Hibernate as implementation provider (see: https://github.com/apache/karaf/tree/master/examples/karaf-jpa-example). Which one of these have you configured in which version? Please update your question with more details (version numbers.. etc.).

Comment: @MWiesner I am referring the above example only also i am using Hibernate feature, and the version is <hibernate.version>5.4.8.Final</hibernate.version>